# Instrinsic center aligned divs with wrapping

Tags: html, css

I am trying to write an element that behaves fluidly in accordance with [Intrinsic Web Design](https://justcreative.com/2018/06/26/intrinsic-web-design/), while satisfying the following conditions:

1. if there is enough space always group the two children together in the middle of the parent, while maintaining a gap between them

[image: Two rectangles grouped in the center of a bigger parent rectangle]

2. if the parent is too small to keep the children together side-by-side wrap them so they are underneath each other

[image: Two rectangles aligned at the beginning of a parent rectangle]

**All of this should be done preferably without media queries and without JavaScript.**

Intuitively, I went with CSS Grid and this is my progress so far:

```css
.wrapper {
  max-width: 100rem;
  padding: 1rem;
  border: 5px solid red;
}

.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
  gap: 1rem 1rem;
}

.one {
  justify-self: end;
  background-color: black;
  width: 10rem;
  height: 10rem;
}

.two {
  background-color: black;
  width: 10rem;
  height: 10rem;
}

#auto-fit {
  margin-top: 3rem;
}

#auto-fit .grid {
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(100px, 1fr));
  gap: 1rem 1rem;
}

#auto-fit .one {
  margin: 0 auto;
}

#auto-fit .two {
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge" />

  <title>StackOverflow Intrinsic Grouping Question</title>
</head>

<body>
  <!-- Correct in landscape mode, but does not wrap -->
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="grid">
      <div class="one"></div>
      <div class="two"></div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <!-- Correct in portrait mode, but is not correct in landscape mode -->
  <div id="auto-fit" class="wrapper">
    <div class="grid">
      <div class="one"></div>
      <div class="two"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

(I initially prepared this in CodeSandbox before I noticed that StackOverflow has its own embedded code environment: [Intrinsic Center Group on CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/intrinsic-center-group-be1um?file=/main.css&resolutionWidth=1112&resolutionHeight=675))

I have the slight feeling that the answer might be very obvious, but I did not find a reference to someone solving exactly this problem with the vocabulary that I am equipped with.

Comment: Do you prefer flex or grid? Flex would be more appropriate from the pictures you've posted.

Comment: I have no preference in that regard. The only two conditions would be no media queries and no JS.

Comment: I gave the solution to the `grid`. Do you need to do the same for the upper blocks (`.one`)?

Comment: Using `grid` has worse compatibility than `flex` and I generally only recommend `grid` if you really can't manage `flex` well enough. I have a visual `flex` tool that I can publish later today if you'd really like to see what `flex` can do?

Comment: @John, nowadays, `grid` can be used quite freely.

Comment: @s.kuznetsov That is wholly dependent on your concept on compatibility.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question can be solved with a `grid`, and **without** `media queries` and `javascript`.

For the first `.grid` grid, add these rules:

```
grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(10rem, auto));
justify-content: center;
```

For the second `#auto-fit .grid` grid, add these rules:

```
grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(10rem, 1fr));
justify-content: center;
```

And you will get the result you want.

```css
.wrapper {
  max-width: 100rem;
  padding: 1rem;
  border: 5px solid red;
}

.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(10rem, auto));
  gap: 1rem 1rem;
  justify-content: center;
}

.one {
  justify-self: end;
  background-color: black;
  width: 10rem;
  height: 10rem;
}

.two {
  background-color: black;
  width: 10rem;
  height: 10rem;
}

#auto-fit {
  margin-top: 3rem;
}

#auto-fit .grid {
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(10rem, 1fr));
  gap: 1rem 1rem;
  justify-content: center;
}

#auto-fit .one {
  margin: 0 auto;
}

#auto-fit .two {
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge" />

  <title>StackOverflow Intrinsic Grouping Question</title>
</head>

<body>
  <!-- Correct in landscape mode, but does not wrap -->
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="grid">
      <div class="one"></div>
      <div class="two"></div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <!-- Correct in portrait mode, but is not correct in landscape mode -->
  <div id="auto-fit" class="wrapper">
    <div class="grid">
      <div class="one"></div>
      <div class="two"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Not too familiar with the Grid layout, but the Flex layout with wrapping and center justify works.

```css
#parent {
  border: 2px solid;
  width: 300px;
  resize: horizontal;
  overflow: auto;
  display: flex;
  flex: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: center;
}

#parent > div {
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  margin: 10px;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div id='parent'>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
</div>
```